# NgFor/NgIf multiply selection(favorites)

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have a weather app, where I want to mark **multiply** favorite cities by a "full heart" icon .

At the moment, when I click on different cities, the city before gets unmarked (kinda still buggy),

so basically I have only a single "full heart" icon showing, instead of afew.

Appreciate the help of modifying my app.

Adding and Removing favorites works as intended (displaying in 'Favorite' route), but I just cant figure

out how to combine it with the favorite icon.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-w3expd?file=src/app/weather-page/weather-page.component.html

**Component.ts**

```js
setLikedCity(index:any){
    this.likedCity = index
  }
  

addToFav(name:any, local:any){
    let favCity = {
        name:name,
        local:local
    }
    console.log("local:", local, "name:", name)
    console.log("this.favoriteLocations:", this.favoriteLocations)
    
        if(this.favoriteLocations.length ==0){
            this.favoriteLocations.push(favCity)
            console.log("this.favoriteLocations:", this.favoriteLocations)
            console.log("ADDED")
        }
        
        else if(this.favoriteLocations.length > 0){
                let index;
                for(let i =0; i<this.favoriteLocations.length; i++){
                    if(this.favoriteLocations[i].name.Key ==favCity.name.Key){
                        index = i
                        // break;
                    }
                }
                
                if(index !=null){
                    this.favoriteLocations.splice(index, 1)
                    this.likedCity = ''
                    console.log("REMOVED")
                
                }else{
                    this.favoriteLocations.push(favCity)
                    console.log("ADDED")
                    }
                console.log("this.favoriteLocations:", this.favoriteLocations)
        }
        this.weatherService.favoriteLocations =  this.favoriteLocations
}
```

**Component.html**

```js
<div class="container">
    <div class="small-container">
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" *ngFor="let name of TelAvivSearch; let i = index;">
                <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center;">
                    <h5 class="card-title ">{{name.LocalizedName}}</h5>
                    <div *ngFor="let local of telAvivLocal ">
                        <p class="card-text ">{{local.WeatherText}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text ">{{local.Temperature.Metric.Value}}°</p>
                        <div *ngIf="i!==likedCity">
                            <i class="far fa-heart" (click)="addToFav(name, local);setLikedCity(i)"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="i===likedCity">
                            <i class="fas fa-heart" (click)="addToFav(name, local);"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- favorites -->
    <div class="forecast-container mt-3 ">
        <h1 style="text-align: center; ">Forecast</h1>
        <div class="small-container ">
            <div class="row">
                <div *ngFor="let forecast of Forecast.DailyForecasts">
                    <div class="card " style="width: 13rem; ">
                        <div class="card-body" style="text-align: center;">
                            <h5 class=" card-title ">{{forecast.Date | date}} </h5>
                            <p class="card-text ">Day: {{forecast.Day.IconPhrase}}</p>
                            <p class="card-text ">Night: {{forecast.Night.IconPhrase}}</p>

                            <p class="card-text ">{{forecast.Temperature.Maximum.Value}}°<span>/ {{forecast.Temperature.Minimum.Value}}°</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following method in your commponent.ts and change the *ngIf condition on html side - it should work now.

```js
  isLikedCity(key: number): boolean {
    const idx = this.favoriteLocations.findIndex(
      x => x.name['Key'] === key
    );
    return idx >= 0;
  }
```

```html
  <div *ngIf="!isLikedCity(name.Key)">
       <i class="far fa-heart" (click)="addToFav(name, local);setLikedCity(i)"></i>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isLikedCity(name.Key)">
      <i class="fas fa-heart" (click)="addToFav(name, local);"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that function calls in template expression context will be called MANY times and may be a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, then probably I would have added an additional property to all the objects of TelAvivSearch array of objects, calling it blFavorite - which will change it's value by pressing the heart. Also displaying it full on html side if the condition is met *ngIf=name.blFavorite.

Comment: I would, but its a response from a weather API that gives you only 50 requests per day (which is nothing), so I had to save the responses and work locally, and later on work with that API again.

Comment: hmm I see, in this case I suggest trying out the method I wrote below (p.s let know if it works for you).

Comment: It worked, Thanks!
Just one question.
The name of a city isnt a unique one, but its Key is (""Key":"3",).
I tried replacing name with key, but got an error when clicked:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Key' of undefined
Could you please try? (name.Key)

Comment: HTML change the given parameter to Key: isLikedCity(name.Key), in TS modify the following line:    x.name['Key']. Also don't forget to change the enter parameter  type of isLikedCity(name: number)

Comment: I changed the code above, it should work.

Comment: Thank you!
Just had to change isLikedCity(key: number) to isLikedCity(key: string)

Answer (score 0):

What I did is:
Added a new key `Liked: 0,` to all the elements in `TelAvivSearch` as seen below:

```
{
        "Version":1,
        "Key":"3",
        "Type":"City",
        "Rank":31,
        "LocalizedName":"Herzeliya",
        "Liked":0,              <<< new key 'Liked' added
        "Country":{
            "ID":"IL",
            "LocalizedName":"Israel"
        },
        "AdministrativeArea":{
            "ID":"TA",
            "LocalizedName":"Tel Aviv"
        }
    },
```

When user hit heart icon - in `setLikedCity` I set `this.TelAvivSearch[index].Liked = 1;` as below:

```
 setLikedCity(index:any){
    this.TelAvivSearch[index].Liked = 1;
 }
```

In the `addToFav` function set the value for `Liked` based on if the item is added/removed from the favourite list as below:

```
            .....
                if(index !=null){
                    this.favoriteLocations.splice(index, 1)
                    this.TelAvivSearch[index].Liked = 0;
                    console.log("REMOVED")
            .....
```

In `html` file, display the heart icon selected based on this value of `Liked` key as

```
<div *ngIf="name.Liked === 1">
    <i class="fas fa-heart" (click)="addToFav(name, local);"></i>
</div>
```

and it works as expected.

Comment: I would do that, but at the moment Im working locally with a response from an API which I saved because that API allows only 50 requests per day.